# Multithreading: when to call mutex.lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

So, I have a ton ob objects, each having several fields, including a c-array, which are modified within their "Update()" method. Now I create several threads, each updating a section of these objects. As far as I understand calling lock() before calling the update function would be useless, since this would essentially cause the updates being called in a sequential order just like they would be without multithreading. Now, there objects have pointers, cross referencing to each other. Do I need to call lock every time ANY field is modified, or just before specific operations (like delete, re-initializing arrays, etc?)

Comment: Do you have some code? From what you write it seems like your class does too much and your problem is in keeping modifications to several disconnected subaspects in sync. If you would compose your class from more targeted classes you could lock on modifications specific to each component (e.g. with multiple locks).

Comment: You can use a global lock if your HW supports lock elision

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to call lock every time ANY field is modified, or just before specific operations (like delete, re-initializing arrays, etc?)

Neither.  You need to have a lock even to read, to make sure another thread isn't part way through modifying the data you're reading.  You might want to use a many reader / one writer lock.   I suggest you start by having a single lock (whether a simple mutex or the more elaborate multi-reader/writer lock) and get the code working so you can *profile* it and see whether you actually *need* more fine-grained locking, then you'll have a bit more experience and understanding of options and advice about how to manage that.

If you do need fine-grained locking, then the trick is to think about where the locks logically belong - for example - there could be one per object.  You'll then need to learn about techniques for avoiding deadlocks.  You should do some background reading too.

Comment: Okay, then multithreading is probably not feasible with my code atm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the consequences of the data changes you want to make. If each thread is, for example, changing well defined sub-blocks of data *and* each sub-block is entirely independent of all other sub-blocks then it might make sense to have a mutex per sub-block.

That would allow one thread to deal with one set of sub-blocks whilst another gets a different subset to process.

Having threads make changes without gaining a mutex lock first is going to lead to inconsistencies at best...

If the data and processing isn't subdivisible that way then you would probably have to start thinking about how you might handle whole objects in parallel, ie adopt a coarser granularity and one mutex per object.  This is perhaps more likely to be possible - different objects are supposed to be independent of each other, so it should in theory be possible to process their data in parallel.

However the unavoidable truth is that some computer jobs require fast single thread performance. For that one starts seriously needing the right sort of supercomputer and perhaps some jolly long pipelines.